# Sphinx document generator: "only" not?

Tags: python-sphinx

The Sphinx document generator provides [`only` markup](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/misc.html#directive-only). For example, the following would only include the external file "only" if its html generator:

```
.. only:: html

   .. include:: a.rst
```

But how would I set "only not"? The following does not seem working, even with braces:

```
.. only:: not html

   .. include:: b.rst
```

Answer (score 0):

`.. only:: not html` should be the correct way to specify it as per [Sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/misc.html#including-content-based-on-tags). The following works for me using sphinx-build 1.2.2:

```
.. only:: html

  This should be HTML format only.

.. only:: text

  This should be text format only.

.. only:: not html

  .. include:: nohtml.rst

  This should be in everything except HTML.

.. only:: not text

  .. include:: notext.rst

  This should be in everything except Text.
```

Comment: What are the contents of your `no.text.rst` and `nohtml.rst`?